# Is it wrong to say that $\theta$ has to be given in "radians" (rather than "circular measure") in, e.g., the formula $\frac12\theta r^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

**Definitions:**

> A **radian** is the measure of the central angle subtended by an arc equal in length to the radius of a circle. The SI symbol for a radian is $rad$

> The **circular measure** of an angle is the number of radians it contains.

**Question body:**

Consider the formula below which is used to calculate the area of a sector of a circle:

$$s = \frac{1}{2}\theta r^{2}$$

In many textbooks for introductory geometry, authors emphasize that the formula holds if $\theta$ is given in radians. However, when we compute, we use the circular measure of an angle given in radians. For example, let the radius of a circle be $6$ and the angle subtended at the centre be $\frac{\pi}{3}$ $rad$, hence we compute as follows:

$$s = (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{\pi}{3})(6^{2}) = 6\pi$$

As you can see, $rad$ is never included because we consider the circular measure of an angle, which is given in radians. Therefore, it yields $6\pi$ and not $6\pi$ $rad$.

**Question:**

As the title suggests, does $\theta$ represent the cirular measure of an angle or just an angle given in radians? Also, please explain why.

Comment: $\theta$ can be considered the angle in radians, or equivalently, the circular measure of the angle on the *unit circle* (i.e. circle of radius $1$). The circular measure is just given by $r\theta$ on a circle of radius $r$.

Comment: Note also that the radian is a dimensionless unit. *"Plane and solid angles, when expressed in radians and steradians respectively, are in effect
also treated within the SI as quantities with the unit one (see section 5.4.8). The symbols rad
and sr are written explicitly where appropriate, in order to emphasize that, for radians or
steradians, the quantity being considered is, or involves the plane angle or solid angle
respectively."* [SI](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure) p. 137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The angle must be given in radians, or it can be the *circular measure*, or arc length, of the arc on the **unit circle** (a circle with radius 1). Think about a circle whose area is $s=\pi r^2$, and we want a portion of that area. Since a circle contains $2\pi$ radians, the area of the sector would be $s=\pi r^2\cdot\frac{\theta \textrm{ rad}}{2\pi\textrm{ rad}}$ and notice that it has to be radians here. Thus, $s=\frac{1}{2}\theta r^2$.

Also, a similar formula can be derived with degrees, but the denominator should be $360^\circ$ instead of $2\pi$. Thus, $s=\frac{\theta^\circ}{360^\circ}\pi r^2$, and remember that $\theta$ here is in radians.

Comment: Let $\theta = 2 rad$, then we get $s = 2r^{2}$ $rad$

Comment: (rad) is a dimensionless *unit*. It's kinda like saying something$^0$. Therefore, $s=2r^2$ excluding "rad", and the unit would just be the radius' unit squared.
Just like @JairTaylor said, radians are defined as a ratio which makes the unit cancel out.

Comment: I think that would only be the case if we consider the circular measure since  $1$ $rad$ $=$ $1$.

Comment: Think about this. If $\theta=2^\circ$, would you say that $s=\frac{1}{180}\pi r^2\cdot degrees$

Comment: Indeed, but why would get rid of $degrees$?

Comment: Do you know the idea that **units** also multiply and divide? For example, the area of a rectangle with side lengths 3 cm and 4 cm would be $3\textrm{ cm}\cdot4\textrm{ cm}=12\textrm{ cm}^2$ not $12$ cm. Thus, in the formula I derived above, the degree unit cancels out. Similarly, a circle has $2\pi~rad$ (which I didn't write out) and it cancels with the $rad$ in $\theta$ if you prefer to understand it that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123987/discussion-between-interstigation-and-nameless).

Comment: @Nameless: degrees exist for historical reasons and are somewhat arbitrary. About their only benefit is that $360$ is a multiple of $24$. A much more interesting unit would be the *revolution*.

Comment: I disagree with this interpretation. Formulas are made independent of the units. F.i. the area of a rectangle is $b\times h$, whatever the units. The same should hold with $\dfrac{\theta r^2}2$, which is possible with an implicit factor $1\text{ rad}^{-1}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not saying that the formula should change. For example, if the unit for the radius is $m$, we are discussing whether the unit of area would be $m^2$ or $m^2\cdot \textrm{rad}$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know that. (like bruh) I was trying to explain it to him. How would you put it in other words

Answer (score 1):

$$\theta=180°=\pi\text{ rad}$$ just like $$l=1\text{ mi}=1.60934\text{ km}.$$

In principle, the unit should always be specified, but in practice it is implicit by context.

Then in formulas like

$$l=\theta r\text{ or }a=\frac{\theta r^2}2,$$ there is an implicit factor $1\text{ rad}^{-1}$, making them valid for $\theta$ in any unit.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The $1$ $rad^{-1}$ comes from $2\pi$ $rad$ in $\frac{\theta}{2\pi rad}$ $\pi r^{2}$, which yields $\frac{1}{2}\theta r^{2}$ $rad^{-1}$ since $\theta$ has to be given in radians as you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote two passages from the question with emphasis added to a few key words.
Here is what the textbooks in question say:

> ... the formula holds if $\theta$ is **given in radians**.

And here is an explanation of the correct method according to you (which I agree with):

> As you can see, rad is never included because we consider the circular measure of an angle, which is **given in radians**.

Is it possible the textbooks are saying the same thing as you? They even use some of the same words.

It seems to me that what the textbooks want you to do **is** to use circular measure. They have merely chosen not to use the particular words "circular measure" to describe it. Instead we have the words "given in radians", which in that context means the number $\theta$ is set to the number of radians that the angle contains,
so that $\theta$ is the circular measure of the angle.

Answer (score 0):

Radians are defined as a ratio: the ratio of the subtended arclength to the radius.  For example, if the radius of the circle is 2 feet and the arclenth subtended by an angle is 4 feet than the angle $\theta$ measured in radians is $$\frac{4 \text{ft}}{2 \text{ft}} = 2$$ with **no** unit since the units cancel.  We **call** this 3/2 radians when it is useful, to remind us that we are working in radians; however the measure of an angle in radians is actually a unitless quantity. In other words, saying $\theta = 2 $ rad is the same as saying $\theta = 2$. $1\, \text{rad} = 1$.

If you want to you can also think of $\theta$ as an arclength along the unit circle; however this is also dimensionless because the unit circle has radius $1$, not radius $1$ foot or $1$ meter.

Comment: I'm still confused. The definition I learned never states that a radian is a ratio.

Comment: What is the definition you know? See the last paragraph I wrote above for an alternate view.

Comment: The first few paragraphs of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) give a good description.

Comment: "More generally, the **magnitude** in radians of the subtended angle is equal to the ratio of the arc length to the radius of the circle". Therefore, radians are not defined by a ratio, the magnitude is.

Comment: There are a few different ways to define what $1$ radian means, but the article is pretty clear that it is a dimensionless quantity regardless.

Comment: No, there's one definition only. $s = \theta r$ is a simplfication for $s = (\theta r )$ $rad^{-1}$ since $\theta$ is given in radians.